# References Request: Bach tensor

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry, tensor

Recently I want to study about Bach tensor in detail. From the fundemental definition and properties to conformal invariant. Is there any references to me about Bach tensor? If there are some origins about how to construct it by Bach, it will be more friendly to me.

Comment: if you Google "Bach tensor" you'll find several pointers to the literature, and there is an earlier [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382967/trace-and-divergence-of-the-bach-tensor) that contains some info that might interest you. For a more helpful response perhaps you can specify what it is that you would like to know, or what puzzles you?